# Laravel 4 pagination

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My pagination doesn't seem to work. Here's how I done it:

```
$players = Auth::user()->players->paginate(2);
```

And then done all the stuff that's needed in the view, but:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate()
```

It shows the line, where that variable is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Auth::user()->players()->paginate(2);
```

`Auth::user()->players` returns a collection, the `paginate` function belongs to the `Builder` class of Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, solved it myself:

**Solution:**

```
Auth::user()->players()->paginate(2);
```